# How to call current objects public method in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, oop

At the moment I came this far.

```
function Class() {

    var privateMethod = function () {
        return 'private'
    }

    this.publicMethod = function () {
        return 'public'
    }

    var _constructor = function () {
        $(document).on('click', _onClick)
    }

    var _onClick = function () {
        // My error is `this`, focus now on the click event, but I need the object itself
        console.log(privateMethod())
        console.log(this.publicMethod())
    }

    _constructor()
}


$(document).ready(init)

function init() {
    new Class()
}
```

The problem is that, in the click event, I am unable to call publicMethod.
I am able to call the private method.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: maybe you should try javascript module pattern. http://briancray.com/posts/javascript-module-pattern

Comment: That kinda looks cluttered. But I'll give it a try, Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that, in your handler you've lost your context (`this` no longer means your instance of Class, it instead means the object that triggered your event.  You need to create a closure scoped version of `this` to hold onto that context.

```
var self = this;
var _onClick = function () {
    // My error is `this`, focus now on the click event, but I need the object itself
    console.log(privateMethod())
    console.log(self.publicMethod())
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a scope issue, `this` in the onclick is pointing to a different object than what you expect. In your case it is the `document`

```
var that = this;
var _onClick = function () {
    // My error is `this`, focus now on the click event, but I need the object itself
    console.log(privateMethod())
    console.log(that.publicMethod())
}
```

[Running Example](http://jsfiddle.net/C4t5S/)

Comment: Also thanks, but I can only accept 1 answer and you both are right :)